# Converting Firebase's ChildByAutoId timestamp to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsdate, firebase-realtime-database

I used `childByAutoId()` save the timestamp as an auto-id. I can successfully retrieve the timestamp key that looks like `-KJrs03bWbSTXfomqzMW`. When I check the key's type, it says AnyObject.

```
 let timestamps = snap.value.allKeys

 for timestamp in timestamps {
      print(timestamp)   // -KJrs03bWbSTXfomqzMW

      if let t = timestamp as? NSTimeInterval {
          print(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: t/1000))
          print("true")
      } else {
          print("false")
      }
  }
```

However, it goes into `false` bit.

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way of converting Firebase timestamps to NSDate?

*PS:*
*I remember I read Firebase allows for a global timing for the items with this kind of timestamp. Is there a way that would enable me to get human-readable version of the time, such as 30mins ago, 5 hrs ago directly working with Firebase or should I use NSDateFormatter?*

---

The node looks like:

```
- -KJrs03bWbSTXfomqzMW
    - "key1": "val"
    - "key2": "val"
```

Comment: i would instead store the timestamp in the model you have for the key.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get. What do you mean as in the model I have for key? I edited my question and added my node type in the bottom. I have it as a node-key. Isn't using `childByAutoId` approach the optimum way of storing timestamps as? Do you mean to storing it inside the node, as `["timestamp": timestamp]`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Where should I put it? I was using `let timestamps = snap.value.allKeys` and then using for the for loop above. (I fixed the wrong naming of variable in the question). For loop works fine for it.

Comment: `for timestamp in timestamps { if let snapkey = snapshot.key as? String {print("true") }`

Comment: Yes, it does return "true" if I try this.

Comment: @senty because its String and you can''t convert it to NSDate as it doesn't have any date formation

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Should I convert the timestamp as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29905645/4705339) and store the timestamp as `"timestamp": timestamp` as a separate key:value?

Comment: @senty no you can't because you don't have any date formation like `2016-06-10 06:05:54 +0000` or miliseconds , etc.

Comment: @senty you can check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift?rq=1

Comment: I tried just exactly that in the very beginning, no? As I get multiple node keys (ie timestamped ids), I used a for loop to separate them and the rest is in the question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114311/discussion-between-ei-captain-v2-0-and-senty).

Comment: @senty Did you ever find a solution to this? Or you switched to using timestamps as El Capitan v2.0 suggested in the chat?

Comment: @toraritte unfortunately, i don't remember how I overcame this as it was in 2016 :(

Comment: @senty No worries, it was worth a shot:) Thank you!

Comment: @toraritte I'm pretty sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift?rq=1) was the answer

Comment: @senty, yeah I saw this above and in your chat. I was just curious whether `childByAutoId` keys could be converted to Date somehow because they are indeed created partially from a client-generated timestamp. Anyway, I figured out a workaround for myself. Thanks again and have a great day!

Comment: @toraritte would be nice if you can add it as an answer :)

Comment: The problem is that it does not answer the actual question. Basically my plan is just adding nodes with `childByAutoId` (that takes care of having them in chronological order) and the node would contain all the data with an extra timestamp attribute (using `ServerValue.timestamp`) just in case.